# Is it bad practice to hold information in the id of an HTML element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Let's say I have a template and I want to loop and create div's. I want to listen to clicks on the buttons contained in each of these divs:

```
<div class="repeatedDiv">
    <button class="reply-button">
</div>

$('.reply-button').on('click',function(e)...)
```

I want to make the reply button function specific to the div that it was selected on. Would it be bad to have something like:

```
<div class="repeatedDiv">
    <button class="reply-button" id="reply-{{this.id}}">
</div>
```

Comment: What type of information? email? yes, color? nope

Comment: @paolo.basso99 As in the example, it would be an identifier for the thing being iterated over in the template. A database id

Comment: Not uncommon to use ID if they are unique, can also use html5 `data` attributes

Comment: I'd use a data attribute for this purpose. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes

Comment: Personally I would store data in a html data attribute, as the Id attribute polutes the global.  Eg.  `data-info`  etc.

Comment: It always depends of what you will store, you must think that ALL your costumers will be web developer so just don't store things like email, password, ecc.

Comment: @mark_c @charliefl I see, I wasn't aware of `data`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't make it more complicated than it really is

```js
$(document).on('click', '.reply-button', function(e){
  var divClicked = $(e.target).closest('.repeatedDiv');
  // do something with clicked div
  // var divClicked is the div elmt that contains the button that was clicked
  // doing it this way you might not even need an id at all
  console.log(divClicked.attr('id'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div1" class="repeatedDiv">
    <button class="reply-button">div1</button>
</div>
<div id="div2" class="repeatedDiv">
    <button class="reply-button">div2</button>
</div>
<div id="div3" class="repeatedDiv">
    <button class="reply-button">div3</button>
</div>
```

And if you do need an id when creating a new div create it dynamically with e.g.

```js
var newID = "id-" + Date.now();
console.log(newID);
```

Comment: There's a difference between trying to make something complicated and not knowing the simple solution :)

Comment: @db2791 That's right. But since I'm not a pro either I'm facing the same problem often enough. Glad I could help ;)